# Hibernate closing MySQL connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-security, struts

I'am unable to log in to my application after some hours of inactivity. Iam using Java, Spring Security, Struts 1.3 and Hibernate.

This is the log i found related to this issue

> 2014-07-30 14:11:40 INFO  LocalSessionFactoryBean:246 - Closing Hibernate SessionFactory

```
java.io.EOFException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1388)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1272)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2236)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1555)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)

/var/lib/tomcat7/logs# 2014-07-30 14:11:40 INFO  SessionFactoryImpl:769 - closing
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at  org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:811)
    at se.etm.ewo.daoImpl.UserDaoImpl.getUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at se.etm.ewo.daoImpl.UserDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:124)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:138)
```

This is my configuration file properties for hibernate

> ```
>   <property name="hibernate.dialect">se.etm.ewo.hibernate.CustomDialect</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://my_ip:my_port/my_database</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
>     <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
>     <property name="show_sql">true</property>
> ```

and this is the spring configuration file properties

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://my_ip:my_port/my_database</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>username</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>password</value>
    </property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize">
        <value>10</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize">
        <value>30</value>
    </property>
    <property name="minPoolSize">
        <value>10</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxConnectionAge">
        <value>3600</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime">
        <value>3600</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">
        <value>1800</value>
    </property>
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts">
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay">
        <value>3000</value>
    </property>
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery">
        <value>SELECT 1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will close idle connections after 8 hours by default(that's the `wait_timeout` parameter in `my.ini` file).

- So, naturally you can edit `my.ini` file and change the value of `wait_timeout`, or just simply type the following command in mysql shell:`SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=86400`
- You can also set a property `validationQuery` in your hibernate config file:

  `<property name="validationQuery">select 1</property>`

  I prefer this one.

Know more about `validationQuery`: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/tomcat/jdbc-pool.html

Comment: c3p0 doesn't seems to work even after a long try. I switched to HikariCP, it works great.

Comment: @ViswanathL Thanks for your notification and I will study into it in my spare time.